# How should I store this information?

Tags: c#

I have a `PrivilegeGroup` table, a `Privileges` table and a `link` table because the `PrivilegeGroup` table and the `Privileges` table is a many to many relationship. I am thinking about load all contents of `PrivilegeGroup` table and `Privilege` table into memory from database at beginning when application started.

I want to save them in a form easily to look up. Usually we will look up the `PrivilegeCode` via `GroupId`.

Which structure is good for this purpose? array of list? dictionary?

Comment: Is this a WinForms or Asp.Net app? (Or possibly console app or workflow hosted in Sharepoint, etc)  That matters, because probably we're going to steer you towards using a well-known security model rather than using your own home-grown one.  (For example, standard Asp.Net membership or Active Directory rather than the direction you seem to be headed.)  Rolling your own is almost never a good idea when it comes to a security model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
Dictionary<GroupIdType, HashSet<PrivilegeCodeType>>
```

This way you can quickly get the HashSet of privileges by GroupId, and do a quick test against the HashSet to check if the privilege exists.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you want to be able to look up PrivelegeCode by the GroupId and don't need any other data? If that is the case then you could use a `Dictionary<GroupIdDataType, PrivelegeCodeDataType>` which should make the lookups easy.

As for loading them all at once on starting the application, I guess it just depends on if changes to this data while the application is running should have any effect on the program without having to restart it.

Comment: one GroupId will have more than one PrivilegeCode.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't think of that at first - the many to many relationship - I'd go with Chris Taylor's answer (using a HashSet as the dictionary value). I'd edit mine to reflect the same thing, but he should get the credit for providing the better answer.

Answer (score 2):

I'll suggest you to keep the data in the instance of DataTable class.

Comment: Not a bad suggestion.   Easy to use, easy to filter and perform lookups.. Has a performance penalty compared to a dictionary, but that's probably negligible.